# AngularJs configure route in callback inside app.config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I developing an application that I need that the routes must load dynamic templates, for an example:

When I hit /myclient/#!/details I need to load templates from "myclient" directory.

I have an json API that responds this configurations for each client.

```
[{
    "path": "/",
    "templateUrl": "template/loja1/index.html",
    "controller": "homeController"
}, {
    "path": "/detail",
    "templateUrl": "template/loja1/detail.html",
    "controller": "homeController"
}];
```

So, I'm having issues trying to setup the angular.config as callback for this API response. I also tried to setup the routes after callback.

I think that this solution would fit. What am I doing wrong?

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $provide) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    var API = $provide.factory('API', function($http) {
        return {
            getStore: function() {
                return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/resources/route");
            }
        };
    });

    var runRote = function(routes) {

        routes.forEach(function(route) {
            $routeProvider.when(route.path, {
                templateUrl: route.templateUrl,
                controller: route.controller
            });
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: "templates/404.html"
        });
    };

    var getRoutes = function(runRote) {
        API.$get().getStore().success(function(data, status) {
            runRote(JSON.stringify(data));
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            runRote();
        });
    };

    getRoutes(runRote);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drica!

Using this implementation that @dfsq send, it will work, but this part

```
app.controller('homeController', function($route) {
    window.route = $route;
});
```

is not necessary if you use ui-route.
Otherwise, this problem in the / route, you can use localStorage to save your json information and reload the page. In my tests, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to stringify routes array when you pass it into `runRote` function. In it you are using `forEach` method on passed data which is an array method, not string. Correct code should be:

```
var getRoutes = function(runRote) {
    API.$get().getStore().success(function(data, status) {
        runRote(data);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        runRote();
    });
};
```

Also configuration for otherwise route should be

```
redirectTo: "templates/404.html"
```

Comment: I changed, but still not working. I don't think that json parser is the main issue.

Comment: Check everything, here is a demo proving that it should work. http://plnkr.co/edit/sSY3slYQlJdZe88gEmvR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @dfsq. But I still having some issues. When I refresh the browser, the page goes blank and the "#!/" don't go the / route. Can you help-me?